# Error with heroku db:push "time zone displacement"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

when I try to push to heroku `heroku db:push` I get this error:

```
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  time zone displacement out of range: "2013-06-02 12:00:00.000000+5895470400"
LINE 1: ...ype", "image_file_size", "user_id") VALUES (1, 0, '2013-06-0...
```

I am running  `ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]` any ideas?

Comment: Google'd your error, top hit seems pretty relevant: https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps/issues/93

Comment: I have taps still doesn't work

Comment: Well, right, it says downgrading to ruby 1.9.2 helped most of the people in the thread.  Have you tried that?

Comment: in my 3rd line i say i am running ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Thread has 1.9.2p318/320 mentioned...  Just trying to help ya, you didn't mention trying anything to fix it, whether it worked before, so I'm stabbing in the dark.

Comment: i appreciate the help i might just have to leave heroku alone